# display things inline on css?

Tags: css

im trying to display things inline using css that should be right next to each other i.e.

**PART1** *part2*

instead of

**PART1**

*part2*

my code is here

http://jsfiddle.net/4EtAf/6/

thanks

Comment: All the below answers are correct, but for the sake of completeness, you can also use dislay:inheret; on the h2 tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `inline` to the `H2` tag. The header is a block level element, which will place a break before and after.

```
.question_area h2
{    
   display:inline;
}
```

The `A` tag is inline by default.

You can also float them, but that is overkill in your case.

Comment: If you want *every* element inside `question_area` to have `display: inline;`, you could use `.question_area * {display: inline;}`, although I’m not sure if this works in IE 6 or 7.

Answer (score 2):

You applied the `inline` css style to the div, not the `h2` or `a` elements. The div will display inline with other divs however :)

Simply add
`h2 {
   display:inline;
}`

Answer (score 2):

You should give the `inline` style to the `h2` elements:

```
h2 { display: inline; }
```

The inline property is not referred to the element being contained but to the element itself. An header tag will be `display: block` by default, and this makes sense since it should be an header.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/4EtAf/8/

You need to display the h2 inline.

You could add a right margin to the `<h2>` 
http://jsfiddle.net/4EtAf/10/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="question_area">
    <h2 style="display: inline-block;"> this is the question</h2>
    <a href="googel.com">google</a>
</div>
```